# Calling python script from javascript that outputs a .txt file

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I need to run a python script that outputs a .txt file from javascript. The script is already done, but I am having trouble calling it from javascript. I am trying to use ajax. Here is the following code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "TXTMaker.py",
});
```

The script is not executed when I trigger this code from a button click. Since the python script outputs the .txt file into a folder, I don't need to save any output, I just need it to be called from javascript.

Comment: You want to call `TXTMarket.py` when `$.ajax` called in javascript code right?

Comment: You'll want to use a framework of some sort. Will you be doing this often?

Comment: `$` refers to jQuery. Have you got the jQuery files on your html page?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do. I will be doing this often, is this not a good approach? And yes, I do have the jQuery files on my html page.

Comment: @shell you probably figured this out already, but are you sure that the python script is in the cgi-bin folder? What webserver are you using? I believe it affects how ajax runs.